# How can I optimize this query of Mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I use Mysql,I have a table with about 800,000 records (TablaUnoOriginal), I need to copy the data to another table (TablaUnoCopia) and then delete the original data, I am doing as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TablaUnoCopia
SELECT * FROM TablaUnoOriginal
WHERE CampoID in (SELECT DISTINCT (CampoID) FROM Key_Table);
```

In this part of the query "SELECT DISTINCT (CampoID) FROM Key_Table" returned 552 records.

The CampoID is an indexed column (Primary Key) in both TablaUnoOriginal and Key_Table tables.

The following query returns approximately 150 records and performing it takes 7 seconds regardless.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CampoID) FROM Key_Table
```

When you run the query, it takes 446 seconds by inserting 1104 rows.

How can I optimize this query?

Thank you.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: You might consider pushing your sub query into a temporary table to prevent it from being executed multiple times.

Comment: @jtimperley: How can you tell it's executed multiple times without seeing results of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Does `TablaUnoCopia` start out empty? What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about this query? Does  `CampoID` stand alone as the PK of `Key_Table`, or is it part of a composite PK? If so, is it the *first* part of that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` over a simple join:

```
INSERT INTO TablaUnoCopia
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM TablaUnoOriginal t
JOIN Key_Table k ON t.CampoID = k.CampoID
```

Make sure there's an index on `CampoID`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`; change it to a JOIN:

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  TablaUnoOriginal AS t
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  DISTINCT CampoID
            FROM  Key_Table ) AS k   USING(CampoID);
```

This assumes that `TablaUnoOriginal` contains an INDEX (or PRIMARY KEY) on CampoID.

Comment: The table TablaUnoOriginal contains a Primary Key is "CampoID".

Answer (score 0):

If TablaUnoCopia starts empty, CampoID is the PK of Key_Table table.

Execute the following Query:

```
EXPLAIN INSERT INTO TablaUnoCopia
SELECT * FROM TablaUnoOriginal
```

WHERE CampoID IN (SELECT CampoID FROM keysTempTable);

Shows the following:

```
Select_type   |     table |     type |  posibble_key |  key |   key_len|    ref |  rows  | extra 
-

SIMPLE  -   keysTempTable   -   ALL -   NULL -  NULL-   NULL-   NULL-   1279  -     Start_temporary

===================================================================

SIMPLE -    TablaUnoOriginal-   eq_ref -    PRIMARY - PRIMARY - 4    -Database_name.keysTempTable.CampoId - 1 - End_temporary
```